# iScroll 5 trackpad speed too fast

Tags: javascript, html, css, iscroll4

I'm doing a simple image gallery with iScroll 5.
Basically I have only 5 images that I can scroll.

If I use clicks and touch (on iPad) works great.

My problem is with trackpads.

So if I try to scroll with trackpad, the scroll jumps from the first image to the last one.

Is there any way I can change the speed of the trackpad?

I'll like not do disable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think trackpad uses the mouse wheel event, so you can try setting that speed. Try something lower than the default 20.

```
var scroll = new IScroll('#wrapper', {
    mouseWheelSpeed: 20 // the default speed
});
```

Resource: http://iscrolljs.com/#configuring

Comment: Yes. I tried. But is not working. Tried 10, 5, 0.5, 0.01 and still the same.

Comment: What browsers have you tried? I noticed that this setting doesn't work in Chrome (v37 on Mac) but works fine in Safari. I checked the code and it's because Chrome is set to scroll by lines instead of pixels, so there doesn't seem to be a way to set the scroll speed without changing IScroll code.

Comment: And if I need to change iScroll code, where can I setup the speed?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have access to IE11. The code to test or change is line 1062 of https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll/blob/master/build/iscroll.js, i.e. "wheelDeltaY = -e.deltaY;". You can multiply it by this.options.mouseWheelSpeed and see what speed works well.

Answer (score 0):

did you enable "snap" option?

In that case, the scroll may fire snap action and jump to the bottom (depending on your page or snap settings).
You can adjust the scroll speed by adding snapSpeed option.
Hope it would work.

Ref: [Related thread on Github](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll/issues/1177).